# Swift: How to change only <img> or image sizes in webView

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I am getting HTML from a server and display it in a UIWebView.The "Scale Page to fit" option is not selected because of the requirement. The UIWebView width is equal to the screen width and height varies according to the content. The image tags in HTML contains some inline styling which are creating some problem in the view of webView.
Screenshots are attached

[image: Some images with small size looks ok]

[image: Some images with large width and height go out of screen]

in 1st Image you can see the image is small because of small size set to it's inline styling. But 2nd one has larger image, so the image goes out of bound.

Is there any way to control the width of the image to equal to the screen width/ UIWebview width ?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution?

Comment: yes @sandy , I got a solution for my case. I omitted all the widths and heights that were assigned to the images in HTML. The webview then adjusted it self within the screen width. 

Do you want me to share the code?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Talha. Though I have fixed this issue by updating the inline styles of image tag in HTML, but your code might help other people who are facing the same issue with webview :)

Comment: Alright I will post the code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code that I used to omit the widths and heights in HTML. The `uiwebview` then adjusted the images within the screen width

```
func HTMLImageCorrector(HTMLString: String) -> String {
    var HTMLToBeReturned = HTMLString
    while HTMLToBeReturned.rangeOfString("(?<=width=\")[^\" height]+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil{
        if let match = HTMLToBeReturned.rangeOfString("(?<=width=\")[^\" height]+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
            HTMLToBeReturned.removeRange(match)
            if let match2 = HTMLToBeReturned.rangeOfString("(?<=height=\")[^\"]+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
                HTMLToBeReturned.removeRange(match2)
                let string2del = "width=\"\" height=\"\""
                HTMLToBeReturned = HTMLToBeReturned.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( string2del, withString: "")
            }
        }

    }

    return HTMLToBeReturned
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add style to your HTML body :

```
let styleContent = "<html><head><style>img{width:100%;};</style></head>" 
+ "<body style='margin:0; padding:0;'>" + (your html body) + "</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the swift 4 version of the HTMLImageCorrector:

```
func HTMLImageCorrector(HTMLString: String) -> String {
    var HTMLToBeReturned = HTMLString
    while HTMLToBeReturned.range(of: "(?<=width=\")[^\" height]+", options: .regularExpression) != nil{
        if let match = HTMLToBeReturned.range(of:"(?<=width=\")[^\" height]+", options: .regularExpression) {
            HTMLToBeReturned.removeSubrange(match)
            if let match2 = HTMLToBeReturned.range(of:"(?<=height=\")[^\"]+", options: .regularExpression) {
                HTMLToBeReturned.removeSubrange(match2)
                let string2del = "width=\"\" height=\"\""
                HTMLToBeReturned = HTMLToBeReturned.replacingOccurrences(of:string2del, with: "")
            }
        }
    }

    return HTMLToBeReturned
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

```
extension String {

func HTMLImageCorrector() -> String {
    var HTMLToBeReturned = self
    while HTMLToBeReturned.range(of: "(?<=width=\")[^\" height]+", options: .regularExpression) != nil{
        if let match = HTMLToBeReturned.range(of: "(?<=width=\")[^\" height]+", options: .regularExpression) {
            HTMLToBeReturned.removeSubrange(match)
            if let match2 = HTMLToBeReturned.range(of: "(?<=height=\")[^\"]+", options: .regularExpression) {
                HTMLToBeReturned.removeSubrange(match2)
                let string2del = "width=\"\" height=\"\""
                HTMLToBeReturned = HTMLToBeReturned.replacingOccurrences(of: string2del, with: "style=\"width: 100%\"")
            }
        }

    }

    return HTMLToBeReturned
}
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to why this code might help OP