# How to resize image in UIWebView from HTML string?

Tags: html, swift, uiwebview, image-resizing

I am showing some HTML string in UIWebView. I want to change width & height of image according to device width. 
I tried to search on google but not found anything which fulfill my requirement.
I am using swift 3

Comment: You can make the size of the Image Dynamic. by passing the width of web view dynamically. Can you confirm you are loading the .html file added in the xcode or writing the HTML code directly in program.?

Comment: Adding some code of what have you done so far might help...

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore i am getting HTML string from server.
<p><img alt="getting pregnant, pregnancy tips" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" style="height:337px; width:600px" /></p>
This is sample HTML string which i am getting

Comment: @SaurabhSinghRathore Can you share the complete HTML String with me. So that i can try to make a dynamic code with that for you

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore edited previous comment with sample html string.

Comment: @SaurabhSinghRathore So the thing is simple. you can replace the Width in HTML with, this let width = Int(webView.frame.size.width). This will capture the width everytime and make it dynamic.If you want formatted HTML string from me please share some more HTML String so that i can convert that for you.

Comment: @AhmadF i followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608366/swift-how-to-change-only-img-or-image-sizes-in-webview
But in my case i am not getting inside while loop.

Comment: @SaurabhSinghRathore Are you getting the response of HTML in String Format.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168529/discussion-between-abhirajsinh-thakore-and-saurabh-singh-rathore).